# printing a pointer to an object

Tags: c++

I have a number class and in the main method i created a pointer to a number object. This object has a string field which contains the value of the number as a string. I'm trying to print that string value with cout but i keep failing. I'm a beginner and i got deep in overloading << operator and stuff but i couldn't find a way too print the pointer,thanks..

```
Number *n1 = new Number();
cout<<*n1;            // That must print the string value
```

Edit : I can write a function to print a number object but it's not the deal. Also i'm familiar with the number->value syntax. I guess what i need to do is overload the << operator to print a pointer to object

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with pointers. You need to figure out how to print a `Number` object.

Comment: Or, if you really want to print a pointer, then just do `cout << n1;`

Comment: Or `cout << n1->number_as_a_string;`

Comment: Useful reading: [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: @solti a getter or `operator<<` overload would be more ideologically correct.

Comment: @user4581301 totally agree

Answer (score 3):

In c++ you can overload all kind of operators, etc. +, ++, -, --, ...
You can also overload << to do whatever you want it to do.

For your example you can do following:

In class definition put

```
class Number
{
public:
    std::string value;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Number& num);
}
```

and then define function however you want.
For example:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Number& num)
{
    os << num.value;
    return os;
}
```

After that operator << on object from class Number will print value saved in string value.

For more informations you can look into: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Number` class looks like that:

```
class Number
{
public:
    std::string value;
};
```

Then you can print value with :

```
Number* n1 = new Number();
std::cout << n1->value;
```